# Разработка игр для iOS на Windows

Tags: ipad, objective-c, iphone

В чем на винде можно писать приложения без ограничивающего функционала для iPhone, iPad?

Хотел бы узнать, что есть из бесплатных сред программирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если писать игры, то подойдет [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org).
Тут инструкция:[Cocos2d-x: Пишем первое кроссплатформенное приложение](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/gdev/126582/)

Answer (score 0):

iphone ipad и windows немного несовместимы в плане разработки. Хочется разрабатывать - нужен мак. Но можно поставить различные ["сборки"](http://yuryskaletskiy.blogspot.com/2008/09/iphone-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Поставь виртуалку на нее mac;)